# Clarification on how word2vec `generate_batch()` works?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have been trying to understand how it works to apply it to my test and dataset (I find that tensorflow code on github is too complex and not very straightforward).

I will be using a skip-gram model. This is the code that I wrote. I'd like a non cryptic explanation of what's going on and what I need to do to make this work.

```
def generate_batch(self):
    inputs = []
    labels = []
    for i,phrase in enumerate(self.training_phrases): # training_phrases look like this: ['I like that cat', '...', ..]
        array_list = utils.skip_gram_tokenize(phrase) # This transforms a sentence into an array of arrays of numbers representing the sentence, ex. [[181, 152], [152, 165], [165, 208], [208, 41]]
        for array in array_list:
            inputs.append(array) # I noticed that this is useless, I could just do inputs = array_list

    return inputs, labels
```

This is where I am right now. From the `generate_batch()` that tensorflow provides on github, I can see that it returns  `inputs, labels` .

I assume that inputs is the array of skip grams, but what is labels? How do I generate them?

Also, I saw that it implements `batch_size`, how can I do that (I assume I have to split the data in smaller pieces, but how does that work? I put the data into an array?).

Regarding `batch_size`, what happens if the batch size is 16, but the data offers only 130 inputs? Do I do 8 regular batches and then a minibatch of 2 inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `skip-gram` you need to feed the `input-label` pair as the `current word` and its `context word`. The `context word` for each `input word` is defined within a window of the text phrases.

Consider the following text phrase: `"Here's looking at you kid".` For a window of `3`, and for the current word `at`, you have two context words `looking` and `you`. So the `input label` pairs are `{at, looking}, {at, you}`, which you convert them into a number representation.

In the above code, the array list example is given as: `ex. [[181, 152], [152, 165], [165, 208], [208, 41]]`, which means current word and its context is defined for the next word and not for the previous word.

The architecture looks something like below:

[image]

Now you have these pairs generated, get them in batches and train them. Its ok to have uneven size batches, but make sure that your loss is `average loss` and not a `sum loss`.

Comment: So, if I understand it correctly this is how an input should look like `[[10,4],[4,12]]` and this is how the context (or label) should look like `[4]`. Is this right?

Comment: The inputs are 10 and 4 for labels 4, 12. Remember word2vec is a encoder-multidecoder architecture, where input dimension and output dimension are same. Convert 10, 4 to a one hot encoded format, then you feed it to the input and output respectively.

Comment: I see, so in this case `inputs[0]` would be `[10,4]` and `labels[0]` would be `[4,12]` (Hope I got it right this time). Two questions: do I need to encode both inputs and labels to one-hot? Encoding to one hot would look like this (`tf.one_hot(inputs, depth=vocab_size, dtype=tf.float32)`) right?

Comment: yes the input representation x1..xv in the image is one hot with depth as vocab_size.